# New to React. Creating an app that authenticates users using Passport+cookies and my state gets lost on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

Reducer

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
import {
  LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  error: '',
  message: '',
  content: '',
  authenticated: false,
  authenticating: false,
  username: '',
  fullName: '',
  password: '',
};

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  console.log('anything?');
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
      console.log(';', action.fullName);
      console.log(';;', action);
      console.log(state.fullName)
      return {
        ...state,
        fullName: action.fullName,
        username: action.username,
        password: action.password,
        authenticating: false,
        authenticated: true,
      };
  return state;
}
```

Action creator

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

import {
  LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
} from './types';

import axios from 'axios';
import cookie from 'react-cookie';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies();

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3001/api';

export const loginUser = (username, password) => {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios
      .post(`${API_URL}/auth/login`, { username, password })
      .then(response => {
        cookies.set('token', response.data.token, { path: '/' });
        cookies.set('user', response.data.user, { path: '/' });
        console.log(cookies.get('user'));
        console.log(username);
        dispatch({
          type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
          fullName: response.data.user.fullName,
        });
        setTimeout(
          function() {
            //window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/dashboard';
          },
          3000
        );
      });
    
  };
};
```

How do I keep my state from getting lost when redirecting from page to page? It seems like when I run window.location.href my page refreshes which seems to be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is don't do that. Refresh in react always results in complete state loss, since your script stops running, page gets reloaded and script started again from initial fresh state.

Quite often login scenarios are implemented by issuing ajax call to get credentials, and when that credentials arrive they get stored in the state.

After that your components would recognize that credentials are present, and your components would display content instead of login.

Such scenarios are often implemented by using react partnering libraries like redux and react router.

Comment: So in my state I'd have to change the isAuthenticated boolean and if it passes true redirect in my component otherwise redirect back to login instead of in my action creater correct? And is it mandatory to use cookies instead of localStorage?

Comment: Yes regarding switching from login to authenitcated content. Regarding cookies, local storage, I do not think it is related to React. In  other words, whatever you do, it is how you would like to approach security and/or what is needed by the sites ou are working with.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `react-router` to navigate through your application instead of `window.location.href`.
About the refresh, as Davorin Ruševljan said, the state is always lost in React when refreshing. You can for example use the localStorage to store your state, and load it in `ComponentWillMount`, then dispatch it to work with your state again.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide an example code of how to use "react-router" to redirect instead of window.location.href?

Comment: For react-router v4 you just render following node: <Redirect to="/wheredoyouwanttogotoday"/>